# How to get the ID of last updated Row in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-update

I have a requirement such that I want to get the id of last updated row in a table and I want to use this id for some other operation.

I don't have column like UpdatedOn , so that I can refer that column.

So is there any function like scope_identity and @@identity(which gives me id of last inserted row id) for Update also.

Please help me out for the same.

Comment: Time to create such a column. Btw, `scope_identity`works also only in this scope and not two days later, so it doesn't replace a `CreatedAt` column either.

Comment: You can not retrieve last update information on row/column basis however you can get this info on table level follow this [link][1]however i think it's useless for you , Best solution will be to create table which stores your update details like userId , datetime , etc.  [1]: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/09/sql-server-find-last-date-time-updated-for-any-table/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
declare @mytable as TABLE
    (
      Id int
    )

Update Table Set Name='Nitin'
OUTPUT INSERTED.Id into @mytable
 where LastName='Varpe'

 Select Id from @mytable
```

Answer (score 9):

Since you're only interested in the last ID updated, then you could simply assign it to a variable in the `SET` clause:

```
DECLARE @LastID INT = NULL

UPDATE 
    SomeTable
SET
    SomeColumn = 'SomeValue',
    @LastID = ID
WHERE
    SomeOtherColumn = 'SomeOtherValue'
```

Comment: Great solution, I would have never thought you can set variables with the updated row values  this way. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look for trigger. Go for After Insert/update trigger. It will always give you the last inserted/updated record ,from the dynamic table called Inserted...

Query:

`Select * from Inserted.` and get whatever field you need.

Comment: Could work, but triggers aren't a good permanent solution. You (or others) will forget that they exist which leads to confusion at best. Why not using a simple stored-procedure to update the table and do the other work then. [Bad habits to kick : abusing triggers](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-abusing-triggers)